# Issue with Faces config schema validation in Eclipse (Kepler)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf-2

I have the following declaration on my `faces-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">
    <name>Arial-Functions</name>

</faces-config>
```

I get the following Eclipse problem:

> cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element 'name' must have no element [children],
>   and the value must be valid, line 6, XML Problem

Also:

> cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'Arial-Functions' is not facet-valid with
>   respect to pattern '($|*|\p{L})(\p{L}|\p{Nd}|*|$)*' for type
>   'null',line 6, XML Problem

Line 6 of the XML is: `<name>Arial-Functions</name>`.

What am I doing wrong? PS: This deploys nicely on TomEE Plus and Wildfly 8.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition the the *name* element in [web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd):

```
<xsd:element name="name"
  type="javaee:java-identifierType"
  minOccurs="0"
  maxOccurs="1">
```

The definition of the *java-identifierType* in [javaee_5.xsd](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd):

```
<xsd:complexType name="java-identifierType">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>

The java-identifierType defines a Java identifier.
The users of this type should further verify that
the content does not contain Java reserved keywords.

    </xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:restriction base="javaee:string">
  <xsd:pattern value="($|_|\p{L})(\p{L}|\p{Nd}|_|$)*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

*Arial-Functions* is not a valid Java identifier.

You can test matches with:

```
boolean match = "Arial-Functions".matches("($|_|\\p{L})(\\p{L}|\\p{Nd}|_|$)*");
System.out.println(match);
```

I expect the JSF configuration parser is not validating the XML against the schema and ignores the *name* element in any case.

Comment: Thanks alot, I checked the *Java identifier* type on the [javaee_7.xsd](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_7.xsd) and used it to match it to my identifier declared. The `hyphen` is not permitted.